# Is it possible to travel on a Schengen visa if it contains a typo?

Tags: visas, schengen, germany

I had applied for Schengen visa of my wife and received it today. But there is a typo in her name. Her middle name has been spelt wrongly. Vinay has been written as Vijay.

Can we travel with this typo in the visa or should I apply for correction? I need to travel next weekend and I am afraid that if I apply for correction then will I get the corrected visa in time or not ?

Comment: Those sorts of errors should be corrected, especially if she's in the system with a wrong name.

Comment: Do not delay, contact the consulate (preferably), or VFS (if you cannot contact the consulate) immediately.

Comment: I wouldn't be worried about this typo. Her visa already in her passport.

Comment: I reapplied for visa correction with an application and the visa was reissued by the consulate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you still have enough days before travel, it's better to contact the consulate and make an attempt to correct it. They may even issue a new visa if the mistake is on their part.

Comment: @pnuts That's a very well known spammy site, the purpose of which is to generate traffic, do blackhat SEO type things, etc. I'm quite sure a less unsavoury site can be found as a source, perhaps even an official site.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Handbook for the processing of visa applications](http://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/policies/borders/docs/c_2010_1620_en.pdf):

> If an error is detected by the issuing consulate after the visa
>   sticker has been affixed to the travel document, the visa sticker
>   shall be invalidated by drawing a cross with indelible ink on the visa
>   sticker and a new visa sticker shall be affixed to a different page.

Which means you have to apply to the consulate which issued your visa to receive an updated visa sticker.